# How can I nest clonable metabox fields on WP?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, meta-boxes

I'm trying to create and use a metabox group of fields and display it on a site. I want to handle it like a blog but I don't want to create more and more subcategories and tags.

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend Tran Ngoc Tuan Anh Plugin

Voìla: https://metabox.io/